# Escaping multiple characters won't work by the jQuery way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, jquery-selectors

I try to escape some characters inside the selector names of my html. The jQuery docs are suggesting the following method, which won't work:

```
var theId = my(S)elector

    $( "#" + theId.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|(),)/g, "\\$1" ) ).css('color', '#f00');
```

instead, while searching, I have found this version which works (by adding the square braces like /([ ):

```
 $( "#" + theId.replace( /([:|\.|\[|\]|(),])/g, "\\$1" ) ).css('color', '#f00');
```

Why does the original jQuery version fail?

Comment: Because the first one has a group, and the second one - a character class. Both are somewhat "strange".

Comment: Try `/([:.\[\](),])/g`

Comment: There are several SO posts showing how to escape special characters. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript